# How to store an element with a lot of fields

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I want to design a database system (I use SQLite)and in a table where I keep the history, I store some values of an employee (name,surname, id, etc..) One of the fields are some working positions which currently are 3, but in the future may increased to 4 or 5... Which is is more clever to do?

1) Have a table with all the fields (among them: wp1, wp2, wp3) and later add a column for the wp3, or

2) Store all these working positions to a diferrent table where i will have 2 fields `id` and `wp` and store the diferrent wp to multiple records?

Comment: Unless you give more concrete details about your data and constraints, what is "clever" to do is purely a matter of opinion. Please provide some example data and DDL.

Comment: The first rule of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is to remove repeating groups.  The second option is more flexible because you remove the repeating group of working positions.

Comment: For 1), it's very ugly to write queries to. For example "Who is working in X?": SELECT name FROM emp WHERE 'X' IN (wp1, wp2, wp3). And you have to edit these queries whenever you change the number of fields. Look at the answer of Nei McGulgan below. There you simply have to join both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a 'working position' a job title? A record of employment at a previous company?

1 is a bad idea.

You probably want something like this:

```
create table employees (
  id int primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table working_positions (
  id int primary key,
  employee_id int not null references employees(id), /* foreign key to employees table */
  ...other attributes of a working position...
);
```